# React Js no está funcionando

Tags: reactjs

soy nuevo en esto de React, estoy tratando de hacer funcionar un ejemplo muy sencillo pero no hay caso. Este es mi código:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page</title>
   <!-- The core React library -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
    <!-- The ReactDOM Library -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="./lander.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**lander.js**

```
function formatName(user) {
  return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
}

const user = {
  firstName: 'Harper',
  lastName: 'Perez'
};

const element = (
  <h1>
    Hello, {formatName(user)}!
  </h1>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hola</h1>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Cuando voy a la página no se muestra absolutamente nada. Logré hacerlo funcionar cambiando los scripts que tengo por

```
<script src="http://fb.me/react-0.12.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js"></script>
```

Y funcionaba, pero se supone que los que estoy importando ahora son los originales que aparecen en la propia página de React. ¿Dónde estoy comentiendo el error?

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Recomiendo que mejor uses NPM e instales create-react-app así para que no tengas problemas con Babel.

Comment: Hola! Esta pregunta la realicé recién cuando me iniciaba no solo en React sino también en la programación web en general. Actualmente uso Webpack-encore para Symfony, Webpack solo para otros proyectos y a veces Parcel. Todos con Babel. Gracias por la sugerencia!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con la segunda opción te funcionó porque usaste `JSXTransformer`, el cual te transforma de jsx a js. El problema con la segunda opción es que estás usando una versión bastante antigua de react (0.12.2) comparada con la primera (15.3.2). Otra cosa es que `JSXTransformer` [ya no está siendo mantenido](https://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html) y deberías usar un transpiler como babel [para generar el js correspondiente](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=function%20formatName(user)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20user.firstName%20%2B%20'%20'%20%2B%20user.lastName%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20user%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20firstName%3A%20'Harper'%2C%0A%20%20lastName%3A%20'Perez'%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20element%20%3D%20(%0A%20%20%3Ch1%3E%0A%20%20%20%20Hello%2C%20%7BformatName(user)%7D!%0A%20%20%3C%2Fh1%3E%0A)%3B%0A%0AReactDOM.render(%0A%20%20%3Ch1%3EHola%3C%2Fh1%3E%2C%0A%20%20document.getElementById('container')%0A)%3B).

De hecho si pruebas tu código, [interpretado como jsx](http://jsbin.com/bumimisiko/edit?html,js,output), verás que no da problemas.

Comment: Hola, primero gracias por responder! Ahora, tengo otra duda, tendría que escribir mi código y cada vez que quiero probarlo compilarlo en ese compilador de Babel que acabas de pasar?

Comment: @Genarito si vas a usar JSX, si, tienes que compilarlo, porque no existen exploradores (que yo sepa) que interpreten JSX. Siempre puedes aprender a escribir react de la forma tradicional (con JS) aunque a la larga se hace tedioso, es cosa de comparar el código que puse en el conversor online. De todas formas hay herramientas que automáticamente te compilan todo esto, como webpack o browserify. [Hay varios tutoriales](https://goo.gl/pKuQqL) y un largo camino de sufrimiento y aprendizaje por delante. Buena suerte